# How come there are more leads than campaign members in campaign?

Tags: campaign-member

We have an active campaign.

[image]
There are 115 Campaign members (both leads and contacts) and 222 leads.

No converted leads, and not contacts.
[image]

How is such a scenario possible?

How come there are more leads than campaign members?

Comment: Maybe you caught the campaign in between updates? There's a note that says that "Campaign statistics calculations may be delayed by up to 10 minutes" when you view a campaign. In this case, I'd guess someone just deleted ~100 campaign members and the system is catching up.

Comment: That was my thought too, but it's the same numbers for 2 days now. Deleting a campaign member will not delete the lead, only the connection to the campaign.

Answer (score 1):

I just replicated this in my org (to an extent). When you convert leads to contacts, the lead counter doesn't go down. If multiple leads are converted into the same contact, it causes two members to collapse into a single record. While possibly unreasonable, it seems the most likely cause was a large number of lead conversions into existing contacts that may have already been on the campaign. I'm pretty sure that Campaign Members should normally equal "Contacts + Leads - Converted Leads."

[image: more leads than members]

Comment: I want to mention, in my screenshot (it's cut, but) the conveted leads is: 0, just saw it. Sorry, but that's not the solution :-/

Comment: That's perplexing. I still think it's probably "working as designed", but maybe there's other ways to trigger this, too, like merging leads or something.